# Autodesk Forge Viewer - Multi-selection on touch devices

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk

I have an application where we use touch devices to work with models. 1 of our features is connected with multiselections. I didn't find the way how to use it on tapEvents. To solve it i used workaround and overrode a handler for tap (skip it) and dispatched click instead. But in the latest versions (~7.51) click handler in forge started checking isMobileDevice by User-agent and skipped further steps.

So the question is: is there is any possibility to have multiselection on touch devices like with click by this way?

```
this.adskViewer.viewer.setCanvasClickBehavior({
  click: {
    onObject: [isMultiple ? 'selectToggle' : 'selectOnly'],
    offObject: ['deselectAll'],
  },
});
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can create an extension to override the selection behaviour.

You can [subscribe](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/developers_guide/viewer_basics/events/) to the `Autodesk.Viewing.SELECTION_CHANGED_EVENT`, keep track of previous selected items and add them to the current selection while the selection is not empty.